# Каким членом предложения является слово "Что" ?

Tags: члены-предложения

Предложение: "Я мог хорошо видеть с утёса всё, что внизу делалось."

Comment: @kato, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Подлежащим в придаточном. Разберите придаточное по составу. Делалось – явно сказуемое. Делалось что? – **что**. Делалось где? – **внизу**, обстоятельство места.

Answer (score 1):

В этом предложении слово «что» является союзом.

Comment: А где начало и где конец в Вашем предложении? И аргумент, если есть.